# Play Scala Logging delayed log message with string interpolation

Tags: scala, logging, playframework

If I do something like this in Scala Play:

```
val x = "Monkey"
Logger.warn(s"Hello there monkey man $x")
```

Can I get an guarantee that the expression I'm passing won't get executed unless the warn log level is set? I see that Logger.warn is defined as pass by name, but does that mean the log message expression isn't executed until needed?

Comment: It's already guaranteed, the `if` prevents the expression from ever being evaluated and since it's passed by name, it won't be until it's used, this is what characterize a call by name.

Comment: This is the code for [warn](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Logger.scala#L110): `if (logger.isWarnEnabled) logger.warn(message)`, if and only if the log level is set to warn the `logger.warn` is invoked.

Answer (score -1):

It will be parsed/executed because the string has to be parsed when being passed as an argument to the `warn` level. Here is a code that proves that:

```
object Logger {
    def warn(s: String) = println("Just ignoring the parameter string, in other words, doing nothing with the string here")
}

def monkey() = {
    println("Can you see that it was executed?")
    "Monkey"
}

Logger.warn(s"Lets see how this goes: ${monkey()}")
```

This codes will print:

```
Can you see that it was executed?
Just ignoring the parameter string, in other words, doing nothing with the string here
```

In other words, the string interpolation was executed.

Comment: warn is pass by name not value.

Comment: define your warn as 
    `def warn(s: => String)`